# Need help about import/aliasing with PHP classes (PHP 5.6)

Tags: php, class, php-5.6

I have this problem. I have three classes, in three different files, within namespace classes\MySql.

I have class C called by class B, and class B called by class A.
What is the correct code for each file?

Each file has namespace classes\MySql, but when i try to import the class (example class C used by class B), i get an error because PHP don't recognize class C.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `require_once("Path/To/Your/Class.php")` ?

Comment: Please show us some code. Your explanation  is too abstract and unspecific. Are you using an auto loader or are you including all files manually?

Comment: I have to point out that PHP 5.6 is obsolete - no new applications should be written using it, it's been completely out of support for almost 10 months now...

Answer (score 0):

To use the namespace autoloading you may need to use `composer dump-autoload` command and install psr-4 section in composer.json file. Show your composer.json file and classes files.